# Atom Vimコマンド(テキストオブジェクト)について

Tags: vim, atom-editor

AtomでVimを使って開発をしています。

AtomのVimでテキストオブジェクトを使用したく、
「vim-surround」パッケージをインストールしました。

「ciw」等のテキストオブジェクトは使用できるようになったのですが、
""で単語を囲む「ysiw"」が効きません。

何か設定方法等あればお教えいただけると幸いです、よろしくお願いしますm(_ _*)m

【追記】

コメントでご指摘頂きました内容を、コメントにも書かせていただきましたがこちらにも追記します。

・Atomエディタに入れたプラグイン
　vim-surround(https://atom.io/packages/vim-surround)

Comment: i) Vim は Atom とは別のエディタの名前です．Atom 上で Vim のような機能・キーバインドを実現するプラグインを使っておられるのだと思いますが，その具体的な名前(とリンク)を挙げてください． ii) テキストオブジェクト，`ciw` などは Vim 自身のもっているコマンドで，恐らく Atom 上でも i) のプラグインが入っていれば使えると思います． iii) `ysiw"` は [tpope/vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) という Vim 用のプラグインで定義されてるものという気がしますが，これは Atom で動くパッケージ（[これかな?](https://atom.io/packages/vim-surround)）とは別物です．こちらも具体的にどういう vim-surround をインストールしたのかを質問に追記してください．

Comment: (あともし Atom 上でほんとうに Vim を動かしてるならそれはそれでまた別の話になってくるので上のコメントは無視してその旨追記ください．)

Comment: 気付くのが遅くなってしまい申し訳ございません。コメントありがとうございます！
Atomのエディタに入れたプラグインは、貼っていただきました<a href="https://atom.io/packages/vim-surround" rel="nofollow noreferrer">vim-surround</a>で間違いありません。
ご指摘いただきました通り、AtomエディタでVimのテキストオブジェクトの機能を実現するパッケージです。
そもそも`ciw`と`ysiw"`を同じもののように考えていたのですが、Yoshさんのお話を伺ったところ、`ciw`はVim自身のコマンド、`ysiw"`はVim用のプラグインで定義されているコマンド、ということのようなので、
<a href="https://atom.io/packages/vim-surround" rel="nofollow noreferrer">vim-surround</a>を入れたとしても`ysiw"`を利用することはできず、他に方法を取らねばならないという解釈でよろしかったでしょうか？？

Comment: <a>タグ表記のミス、大変申し訳ありません…。次回以降気を付けさせていただきます。(陳謝

Comment: 遅くなりました． 1. 「テキストオブジェクト」は Vim が持っている機能（というか概念）です．`ciw` などはそれを使った一例 (`iw` = inner word) で，プラグイン無しで使えます．`ysiw"` 等は，そういう概念を元にして vim のプラグインで拡張して使えるようになるものです．従って「同じようなもの」という理解はそんなに間違ってなくて，ただ前者は素の Vim でも使えるということです． 2. Vim 機能の実現のために使っておられるのは [vim-mode-plus](https://atom.io/packages/vim-mode-plus) ということでいいでしょうか？もしそうなら，この機能自体は（マッピングが定義されてないだけで）組み込まれているようで，[vim-mode-plus-keymaps-for-surround](https://atom.io/packages/vim-mode-plus-keymaps-for-surround) というのを追加で導入したら使えそうです．

Comment: Yoshさんありがとうございます！
はい、「vim-mode-plus」を使っておりまして(こちらも初めに記載しておくべきでしたね…、学習しました；)、お教えいただきました「vim-mode-plus-keymaps-for-surround」をインストールしましたところ`ysiw"`が使えるようになりました.
Vimと同じように、マッピング定義を拡張する必要があったのですね.知識不足で調べても見つからず困っておりました.
この度はプログラミングもスタック・オーバーフローも初心者の新参者に丁寧に教えていただき本当にありがとうございました！
ここではお礼に「信用度」を上げる(？)ようですが、どうやら回答として書かれていないと上げることができないみたいなので、あれでしたら回答の方に何かお書きいただければ幸いですm(_ _*)m

Comment: テキストオブジェクトの解釈についても説明いただきありがとうございました*

Comment: せっかくなので回答にしました．お役に立てたようでよかったです，こちらこそ丁寧にありがとうございます．

Answer (score 0, accepted):

わかりきったところも含めて整理するとこうなります．

- Atom も Vim もエディタの名前です．
- 「Atom で Vim を使う」というのは．この場合 Atom にパッケージを導入して Vim のようないろんな機能やキーマップを実現するというもので，具体的には [vim-mode-plus](https://atom.io/packages/vim-mode-plus) を使っておられるということでした．なお， Vim-mode-plus については作者によるチュートリアルもあるので<sup>[1]</sup> 参考になると思います．
- [テキストオブジェクト](http://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-ja/motion.html#text-objects) というのは Vim の持っている概念（あるいはそれを実現するコマンド）のことです．たとえば， `c` (change) というオペレータと，`iw` (inner word) というテキストオブジェクトを組み合わせることで， `ciw` と打つことでその単語を変更することができます．これは， Vim ではプラグイン無しで使えるコマンドです．他のエディタ上でVim を模したプラグイン(今回の vim-mode-plus とか[evil](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil) とか)を使う場合でも，同様に追加のプラグインを必要とせずに使えることが期待されます．
- [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) というVim のプラグインがあって，これは例えば `ys`+`iw`+`"` で単語をクオートで囲えるようにするものです（真ん中の `iw` は前述のテキストオブジェクト）．これは Vim 用のプラグインで，vim-mode-plus 上で動くものではありません．
- 同名の [vim-surround](https://atom.io/packages/vim-surround) というパッケージが Atom にあるようで，今回はこれをインストールしはったのだと思います．これは [vim-mode](https://atom.io/packages/vim-mode) を前提に visual mode で `s)` などのコマンドを提供するもので， `ysiw"` はサポートされていないようです．
- さて，vim-mode-plus ではふつうのテキストオブジェクトは使えるようになっているようです．`ciw` は vim-mode-plus だけで使えるということです．
- `ysiw"` のように「括弧やクオートで囲む」ということについては， vim-mode-plus では「実装はしてるけど，デフォルトのマッピングはない」という[状況のようです](https://atom.io/packages/vim-mode-plus#surround-not-work)．自分で設定するか，おすすめ通り [vim-mode-plus-keymaps-for-surround](https://atom.io/packages/vim-mode-plus-keymaps-for-surround) を追加でインストールすることで解決できそうです．

[1]:   [Vim/vim-mode-plus for Atom: 秒速で初心者からエキスパートになる。 たった７ステップで。](https://qiita.com/t9md/items/1c2f27684703847de2be#3-%E3%82%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E3%81%88%E3%81%88-operator-%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8B%E3%81%88%E3%82%84)

Comment: お礼遅くなり申し訳ありません…！
この度はまとめまで頂き、わかりやすく丁寧なご回答ありがとうございました.
リンクでご提示いただいたチュートリアルも、とても役に立ちそうです、勉強させていただきます！
この度は本当にありがとうございました*

Comment: 何度も連投失礼致します.
回答の左上にある数字の上下ボタンを押すことでお礼ができるものだと思っているのですが、「信用度15以下～」といったようなメッセージが出るのみで番号が変わりません.
これで大丈夫だと思うのですが、何かお礼の仕方が間違っていましたらお手数ですがお申し付けください.
問題が無いようでしたら、こちらのコメントは無視してくださいませm(_ _*)m